# android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a simple code of few lines
making calculator having basic functionalities like addition,sub etc.
but after implementing first operation I started my program and got errors.

[image]

after this theses errors showed by the android studio.

[image]

Comment: Please add to your question code of your activity (not screenshots).

Answer (score 0):

you had not set editSecond you set editFirst two times by mistake:

```
editFirst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editfirst)
editFirst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editsecond)//<-here you are setting editfirst instead of editSecond change it 


editSecond = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editsecond)//<- change above line to this
```

Answer (score 0):

`editsecond` (line 32) is null because you copypasted `editfirst=(EditText) findById(R.id.editfirst)` but forgot to rename your variable (line 21).